# Math Complex conjugate confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am confused by the concept of complex conjugate with a complex exponential

$$\text{Is the complex conjugate}:\overline{2ie^{ix}}=-2ie^{-ix}?$$

I am thinking that the complex conjugate of $2i$ is $-2i$ and the complex conjugate of $e^{ix}$ is $e^{-ix}$.  Is my proposed solution $-2ie^{-ix}$ correct?

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Only for $x$ real, not complex $x$.

Comment: Yes. Complex conjugation is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Is everything clear now?